# CRC32 Mpeg checksums don't match?

Tags: encryption, checksum, crc, mpeg, crc32

I've been trying to reverse engineer a crc32 checksum.  I don't have access to the original J# code as it is compiled and decompiling it has not been helpful.  I ran 10 payloads through [reveng](http://reveng.sourceforge.net/) which returned:

> width=32 poly=0x04c11db7 init=0xFFFFFFFF refin=false refout=false xorout=0x00000000 check=0x0376e6e7 name="CRC-32/MPEG-2"

I tried running the packages through two different python libraries and even constructed an objective-c algorithm to try to get the known checksums.  The recreations all matched each other, but they did not match the original checksums.  Any ideas?

Here are the original and calculated crc32 checksums:

```
original  -> calculated

1.  0x99c93052 -> 0x13bc2c5c
2.  0xb5cea403 -> 0x1fd00c8e
3.  0xc7e4f40c -> 0xf9698bd6
4.  0xabe5ad28 -> 0x6be300d6
5.  0x2dacbf16 -> 0x43b2c356
6.  0xf321c2E9 -> 0xacb5981a
7.  0x01430cb6 -> 0x2f9e64ee
8.  0xa1028afb -> 0x44c7182b
9.  0xe73118e6 -> 0xd6c1ffa5
10. 0x5f366305 -> 0x84961d17
```

Any and all suggestions are appreciated!

**Edit:**

As per request here are original payloads with their CRC-32/MPEG-2 checksum and their calculated checksum:

```
1. Payload = d3b09900005500005469746c653a090954657374207469746c652020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020200a4172746973743a09095465737420617274697374202020202020202020202020202020202020200a43443a0909095465737420434420202020202020202020202020202020202020202020200a4c6162656c3a0954657374204c626c202000
   Orig = 0xf9297a54
   Calc = 0xebcc0d91
2. Payload = d3b09900004300005469746c653a090954657374207469746c652032202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020200a4172746973743a09095465737420617274697374202020202020202020202020202020202020200a43443a0909095465737420434420202020202020202020202020202020202020202020200a4c6162656c3a0954657374204c626c202000
   Orig = 0xb518dad0
   Calc = 0x45e4e895
3. Payload = d3b09900004300005469746c653a090954657374207469746c652033202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020200a4172746973743a09095465737420617274697374202020202020202020202020202020202020200a43443a0909095465737420434420202020202020202020202020202020202020202020200a4c6162656c3a0954657374204c626c202000
   Orig = 0xe367073b
   Calc = 0x5db5800c
4. Payload = d3b09900004300005469746c653a090954657374207469746c652034202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020200a4172746973743a09095465737420617274697374202020202020202020202020202020202020200a43443a0909095465737420434420202020202020202020202020202020202020202020200a4c6162656c3a0954657374204c626c202000
   Orig = 0x44d90b1d
   Calc = 0x14039bc3
```

This is one way I calculated those checksums (although [pycrc](https://pycrc.org/) and the objective-c code I implemented all gave the same results):

```
>>> import crcmod.predefined
>>> s = 'd3b09900004300005469746c653a090954657374207469746c652034202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020200a4172746973743a09095465737420617274697374202020202020202020202020202020202020200a43443a0909095465737420434420202020202020202020202020202020202020202020200a4c6162656c3a0954657374204c626c202000'
>>> crc32_func = crcmod.predefined.mkCrcFun('crc-32-mpeg')
>>> print hex(crc32_func(s))
0x14039bc3
```

The above code used payload example 4.  As you can see the calculated checksum (0x14039bc3) does not match the original checksum that came with the payload (0x44d90b1d).

Comment: We have access to neither the original code nor your recreations, so your table would appear to be useless, unless I'm misreading something. Can you provide us with at least one (small) payload and the checksums produced?

Comment: Please provide an example message and original checksum.

Comment: I've added some payloads to the post.  Hopefully that helps us solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out just passing the hex as a string doesn't end up with the right checksum via the python library [crcmod.](http://crcmod.sourceforge.net/crcmod.html)  It won't take a bytearray either, which seemed to be a more probable way of calculating an accurate checksum.  What you need to do is pass the bytearray as a buffer, and then the correct checksum is calculated.

Using the example in the question:

```
>>> import crcmod.predefined
>>> s = 'd3b09900004300005469746c653a090954657374207469746c652034202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020200a4172746973743a09095465737420617274697374202020202020202020202020202020202020200a43443a0909095465737420434420202020202020202020202020202020202020202020200a4c6162656c3a0954657374204c626c202000'
>>> h = s.decode("hex")
>>> b = bytearray(h)
>>> crc32_func = crcmod.predefined.mkCrcFun('crc-32-mpeg')
>>> print hex(crc32_func(buffer(b)))
0x44d90b1d
```

So there you have it.  It was mostly just a lack of understanding of how CRC checksums are calculated I guess.  Hope this ends up helping someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I can verify all your original CRCs with my Pascal Rocksoft implementation and
the CRC-32/MPEG-2 from http://reveng.sourceforge.net/crc-catalogue/ with these parameters

```
width=32 
poly=0x04c11db7 
init=0xffffffff 
refin=false 
refout=false 
xorout=0x00000000 
check=0x0376e6e7 
name="CRC-32/MPEG-2"
```

If in doubt about implementation, see the C source code included in the [Rocksoft document](http://www.ross.net/crc/download/crc_v3.txt). You find a Python implementation at https://pycrc.org/models.html (although I did not test this).

It seems clear (from your own reveng answer, from Marc's post, from my
confirmation) that the given parameters are correct for your problem. But because
you did show any code, the only suggestion I can give this that you should
debug your code by comparing step-by-step with a proven C implementation.

Comment: The Rocksoft code gave me 0xc315f8fc as a checksum for payload example 4.  I probably haven't figured out how to properly implement it yet... Either way if it gives me the same result as pycrc (which is should, right?) then we're back to square one.  I think there's probably something else I'm doing wrong.  I've added the python code I was using if that helps.